# Gracefully exit heroku worker running a JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I've got a node script running on a heroku worker that is scheduled to run every day at 12:30am. It's actually running repeatedly throughout the day becuase of [heroku's restart policy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-crash-restart-policy).

```
2021-01-26T16:53:45.336648+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-01-26T16:53:45.370113+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I've been searching online on how to gracefully shut down my node process after the script finishes but nothing has worked so far. I've had no joy with process.exit(0) or by shutting down the worker using their 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/$APP_ID_OR_NAME/dynos/$DYNO_ID_OR_NAME/actions/stop' endpoint.

The code is simple. I'm getting data from a service and posting it into another service. Heroku builds the code using webpack and then runs `node dist/main.js`. It looks something like this.

```
const postAllData = async () => {
  const data = await getData();
  await postData(data);
  
  console.log(' Script finished successfully');
};

postAllData();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using a different service to host a node server and using node-cron to queue the running of the script.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this in the future:

Heroku has [three dyno configurations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-configurations): Web, Worker, and One-off. Both Worker and Web processes are intended to be always-on and running. However, the [One-Off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#formation-dynos-vs-one-off-dynos) are capable of running for short periods of time and don't fall under [heroku's restart policy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-crash-restart-policy).

> One-off dynos never automatically restart, whether the process ends on
> its own or whether you manually disconnect.

Also note that the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) executes jobs via One-off dynos.